# chrome extension: Can chrome.storage.get get before dom is loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making chrome extension that block the specific domain from google search ,block list is stored in chrome.storage via popup.html input.My problem is
when "run_at" : "document_end",it shows blocked domain a second and then blocked domain disappear and show less result in one page even there are page 2,3,4...
When "run_at" : "document_start", it doesn't work at all.
I tried directly write domains inside if block,it works perfect.
This is what I want:
Google search open, and immediately show search results (usually 10 web sites) without blocked domain.
How can i correct my source?Thank you.
**block.js**

```
chrome.storage.local.get('key', function(result) {
  const Data = result.key;

  if (!window.google_block) {
    const update = _ => [...document.querySelectorAll(".srg>.g")].forEach(e => {
      const a = e.querySelector(".r a")
      const hostname = new URL(a.dataset.href || a.href).hostname
      e.hidden = Data.includes(hostname)
    })
    const mo = new MutationObserver(update)
    mo.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    })
    window.google_block = true
  }
})
```

;

Comment: Use document_start, only read the storage, put the main code in DOMContentLoaded event listener?

Comment: @wOxxOm ; Thank you for reply. I'm new to javascript and chrome extension so I really wonder where to put main code. Here's my files [block.js , manifest.json , popup.html , popup.js ] Or create new file? If so,put 2 files in content_scripts , file1 [ read storage] file2 [ main] Is this correct?  I would appreciate it if you could give me advice

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify/narrow what you are asking. Currently, you ask one (yes/no) question in the title, then dramatically broaden it to "How can i correct my source?" in the question text (which is too broad). If you're asking us to debug, then you need to provide a [mcve].